# Unable to run project with anything but local codebase in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, java-web-start

I'm trying to build my Java Web Start application using Netbeans.
I realized that if I change the codebase option in the properties options to anything but local I get an error saying

```
Project cannot be run with non-local codebase. Open project properties dialog and set Web Start Codebase to Local Execution.
```

A week or two ago I was able to run it with a "User Defined" codebase. I'm not aware of a change I've made that could have resulted in this. I can build the project, just not run it, is this to be expected?

Any idea whats causing this and how/if I can run this with a non-local codebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out why this was happening, it turns out that this is intentional. As when you run a project in NetBeans you are running it locally, it would be incorrect to try and serve it from a non-local codebase. Hence the ant script in the project ensures that you're running it with a local codebase.

However, you can always build it with a non-local codebase, deploy the jar file, and then test it out.

Sadly there is no way to create a different build profile to build it with a non-local codebase, when you want it, and built it with a local codebase at other times.